# Работа с view из потока new Thread(new Runnable()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Изучаю потоки, вроде всё понял. Но в одном уроке столкнулся с непонятной ситуацией. Как известно, из дополнительного потока Thread нельзя напрямую взаимодействовать с вьюшками - вылетает ошибка. Необходим мостик Handler. Но в данном примере происходит непонятное - на одном компьютере ошибка есть, а на другом компьютере этот же код работает БЕЗ ОШИБКИ. Такое впечатление, что работа кода зависит от конкретного компьютера. И в уроке написано, что приложение должно упасть, но у меня НЕ ПАДАЕТ, работает как-будто существует Handler, и считает количество "Закачано файлов: " .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvInfo;
Button btnStart;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvInfo = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        downloadFile();
                        tvInfo.setText("Закачано файлов: " + i);
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    });
}

void downloadFile() {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под словом - компьютер? может мобильный телефон?

Comment: Я работаю в андроид-студио. Код проверяется в эмуляторе мобильного телефона на компьютере.

Comment: Так, если без handler не работает, почему вы его не использует?

Comment: Да, такие баги могут быть, иногда tvInfo находится в кэше того ядра и/или потока который привязан к ядру, а иногда нет, и происходит NPE, такие дела.

Answer (score 1):

можно обновить вью из рабочего потока таким способом

```
tvInfo.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvInfo.setText("");
                }
            });
```

Handler виполняется в том потоке в котором был создан, можно и его использовать если создать в UI потоке